# Issue with horizontally resizing BMP Image (C#)

Tags: c#, bmp, cs50

Link to Project: https://github.com/FFladenmuller/resize-bmp

Code works for a resize with a factor of 1. However, if trying a larger factor and I open the image, Photos says: "It looks like we don't support this file format".

I have not added in padding yet but I have only worked with images whose width is divisible by 4.

For loop to add BGR bytes to new Image:

```
for (int i = 54; i < oldBMP.Info.Count - 2; i += 3)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < sizeMultiplier; j++)
            {
                newBMP.Info.Add(oldBMP.Info[i]);
                newBMP.Info.Add(oldBMP.Info[i + 1]);
                newBMP.Info.Add(oldBMP.Info[i + 2]);
            }
        }
```

First for loop to increment through BGR triples, second for loop to add each pixel sizeMultiplier amount of times.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Define the following method:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, Size size)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)result))
        {
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return image; 
    }
}
```

Then, within your code, whenever a resize is needed:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Path\MyImage.bmp");

Single scaleWidth = 1.2f;
Int32 targetWidth = (Int32)((Single)image.Width * scaleWidth);

Single scaleHeight = 1.0f;
Int32 targetHeight = (Int32)((Single)image.Height * scaleHeight);

Size size = new Size(targetWidth, targetHeight);

Bitmap imageResized = ResizeImage(image, size);
```

An alternative (that has the drawback of reducing the output quality) is the following:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Path\MyImage.bmp");

Single scaleWidth = 1.2f;
Int32 targetWidth = (Int32)((Single)image.Width * scaleWidth);

Single scaleHeight = 1.0f;
Int32 targetHeight = (Int32)((Single)image.Height * scaleHeight);

Bitmap imageResized = new Bitmap(image, targetWidth, targetHeight);
```